# Two-fingered scrolling is slow in Windows 8 modern UI aka Metro

Tags: windows-8, performance, touchpad, modern-ui, scrolling

I own a Packard-Bell te69hw. It has an ELAN tech touchpad built-in.
The issue is that the scrolling is really slow in Metro. It works perfectly fine in desktop mode. The problem was the since day one.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is the scrolling slow as in there is a delay? Or as in it's choppy like it misses frames? Also, are you referring to the entire metro UI such as the start screen or within specific apps?

Comment: Everywhere in modern UI is moving like my trackpad is very low on sensitivity. Like Counter-Strike

Comment: Like counter-strike sensitivity 1.